# Insert query using dbForge is not inserting default values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert default values into a newly created table, however the table is  created with no values. How can I insert values using dbForge after creating the table?

My Controller code is as follows:

```
    $fields = array('id' => 
                    array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 11,
                    'unsigned' => TRUE,'auto_increment' => TRUE),
                    'home_bg' => array('type' => 'VARCHAR','constraint' => '200',),
                    'login_bg' => array('type' => 'VARCHAR','constraint' => '200',),
                    'other_bg' => array('type' =>'VARCHAR','constraint' => '200',),
                    'uploaded_on' => array('type' => 'DATE',),);
    $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
    $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
    $this->dbforge->create_table('pr_backgrounds', TRUE);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out this

```
     $fields = array(
                            'id' => array(
                                             'type' => 'INT',
                                             'constraint' => 11,
                                             'unsigned' => TRUE,
                                             'auto_increment' => TRUE
                                         ),
                            'home_bg' => array(
                                                     'type' => 'VARCHAR',
                                                     'constraint' => '200',
                                              ),
                            'other_bg' => array(
                                                     'type' =>'VARCHAR',
                                                     'constraint' => '200',
                                              ),
                            'uploaded_on' => array(
                                                     'type' => 'DATE'
                                              ),
                    );

        $this->dbforge->add_field($fields);
        $this->dbforge->add_key('id', TRUE);
        $this->dbforge->create_table('ipn_log', TRUE);
```